# Active Admin + Chosen - screen scrolled to the left

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, jquery-chosen

I've came across a strange bug integrating active admin and chosen.

When I'm scrolling right to the filters sidebar and I choose a select option - the screen is "scrolled back" to the left.

A screencast demonstrating the problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBbDHTtAF-Q

Live implementation: http://aachosen.herokuapp.com/admin/foos (user: admin@example.com pass: password)

Code is based on https://github.com/inossidabile/mastering_aa

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: What browser and screen resolution are you using?